# Subselect in LEFT JOIN hql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a query that uses a subselect in a LEFT JOIN clause of my query
every time I run the query it gives the `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: (` error. with the '(' being the opening parenthesis of my subselect.

my query looks something along the way of:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN t1.table2 as t2
INNER JOIN t1.table3 as t3
INNER JOIN t3.table4 as t4
LEFT JOIN ( //<- this one gives the error
    SELECT d, e, f
    FROM table9 as t9
    ....
) as xx WITH xx.prop = t2.prop and xx.prop2 = t4.prop
WHERE t1.yy = true and t1.zz = '0'
GROUP BY t2.column
```

I have the same query in sql and when I run it in MySQL workbench it works and returns the data that I need. When I use the HQL version it gives an error on the `(` that opens my subquery.

Is this kind of subquery possible in HQL or should I use SQL for it?

And if so what did I do wrong?

**EDIT**:
I tried changing the `WITH` to `ON` and it still gives the same error.

The inner joins work fine, since this is HQL with a configuration in Java that automatches foreign keys so I don't need an on/witch clause on every join.

**EDIT2**:

if I comment the left join the query works, so it's not the lack of `on` or the use of `with`instead of it that is causing me trouble

Comment: `WITH` should be `ON` and you're missing an `=` between `xx.prop2` and `t4.prop`,  but those sound like separate problems or the syntax error would occur on a different line.

Comment: This code makes no sense:  `xx WITH xx.prop = t2.prop and xx.prop2 t4.prop`.  I don't know any database where it would.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I added the missing `=` and `with`is the hql version of an `on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you join with that table, you need to use the `ON` keyword.

```
   LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT d, e, f
        FROM table9 as t9
        ....
    ) as xx ON xx.prop = t2.prop and xx.prop2 = t4.prop
```

Also you forgot the `=` in the join of the second property.

EDIT:

> A subquery must be surrounded by parentheses (often by an SQL
>   aggregate function call). Even correlated subqueries (subqueries that
>   refer to an alias in the outer query) are allowed. Note that HQL
>   subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

From this, you cannot have a sub-query in the from clause.

Comment: @Jorrit If you remove the left join section, does the query still execute, because it seems like the lack of "ON" is where it is breaking

Comment: yes, if I comment the left join the query gives me the requested data, without the data from the last join ofc

Comment: @Jorrit Updated my answer, unfortunately it is not allowing in the from clause.

Comment: oooh ok thanks, I'll have to use the SQLquery instead of the HQL one I guess